# how to pass many variable with tag <a>?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass on three variables using tag `<a>` and jquery, I pass two variables using the name and identifier and the class. I tried to use the value in tag `<a>` But it did not work.
this is tag `<a>`:

```
        <a href="#inserts" class="add_result" 
id="<?php echo $row1['id_visits'];?>" 
name="<?php echo $id_patient;?>"
     value="<?php echo $row1['id_testing'];?>">اضافة نتائج</a>
```

this is jquery

```
$( "a.add_result" ).click(function() {
     var id_visits1 = $(this).id;
     var id_patient1 = $(this).name;
     var id_testing1 = $(this).value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "result_form.php",
            data: { id_visits:id_visits1,id_patient:id_patient1,id_testing:id_testing1  } 
});
```

Any idea to help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For validity and safety of your code use `data-`-attributes:

```
<a href="#" data-id="id" data-name="name" data-value="value"></a>
```

Jquery has a [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function which helps to get `data`-attributes values:

```
$( "a.add_result" ).click(function() {
     var id_visits1 = $(this).data("id");
     var id_patient1 = $(this).data("name");
     var id_testing1 = $(this).data("value");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @u_mulder
I wish you a happy life

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an `onClick` event. The code below is working.

```
<a href="#inserts" class="add_result" id="id_visits" name="id_patient" value="id_testing" onClick="clickMe(this)">اضافة نتائج</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    function clickMe(element){
        var id = $(element).attr('id');
        var name = $(element).attr('name');
        var val = $(element).attr('value');

        alert(id+' : '+name+' : '+val);
    }
</script>
```

This is helpful if you want to get the value of the certain attribute or attributes of any element.